# accessing Groupby Sum results

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I'm trying to do a groupby/ sum to a dataframe,

this is my code:

stage1.groupby(['Year']).sum().max())

it is giving me the value of the maximum sum which is great but I would like to know how to get the year value as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

also any idea why I can't access the values of a groupby/sum to plot it:
years= table['Year'].values
values=table['Value'].values

Comment: Do you need `table = stage1.groupby(['Year']).sum().reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael. That was exactly what I needed. thank you so much